# Integral of matrices

Tags: integration, matrices

I want to perform the following integration:
$$ \int_0^{dt} e^{-\kappa s}\Sigma\Sigma^T e^{-\kappa^T s} ds $$
where $\kappa$ is a $5\times5$ matrix as well as $\Sigma$. Is there any way to solve this analytically?

Comment: What do you mean by using $dt$ as an extremal of integration?

Comment: It's just a scalar upper limit.

Comment: Is there anything else known about $\kappa$? Is it maybe orthogonal by any chance?

Comment: Both $\kappa$ and $\Sigma$ are independent of s. They are both also positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can compute $e^{-\kappa s}$ using Jordan decomposition of $\kappa$. The integration of the matrices can then performed element-wise. It is certain doable, but presumably is a *lot* of work.